# Cannot read property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una librería en jQuery que añade clases a otra cases ya creadas u otros ids directamente con un método addClass() definido en ella, esta es la librería:

```
class gquery{
    constructor(el){
        console.log(el);
        if(el.indexOf('.') > -1){
           el= el.replace('.', ' ' );
           this.elements =document.getElementsByClassName(el); 
        }
        else if(el.indexOf('#') > -1){
           el = el.replace('#', ' ' );
            this.elements=[document.getElementById(el)];
        }
        else{
            this.elements=document;
        }
        
    }
    addClass(cl){  //adding classes automatically
        var count = 0;
        while(count < this.elements.length) {
            this.elements[count].className += " " + cl;
            count++;
        }
    }
}

//to not use word "new" when creating new items of this class
function gQuery(el){
    var element= new gquery(el);
    return element;
}
```

La cuestión es que funciona cuando añado la clase  otra clase cualquiera del documento:

```
gQuery(".my-selector").addClass("HOLA");
```

Sin embargo cuando intento añadir otra clase a un id, tal que:

```
gQuery("#main").addClass("juose");
```

Por alguna razón no funciona, me sale el error "Cannot read property 'className' of null" pero no veo donde puede estar el error.

este es mi html:

```
        <main>
            <section id="menu">
                <form action="submit.php">
                <textarea class="text" placeholder="type something"></textarea> <br />
                <button id="append">Append</button>
                <button id="prepend">Preppend</button>
                <button id="replace">Replace</button>
                </form>
            </section>

            <section id="main">
                <img src="/images/google-stadia-logo.jpg">
                <p class="my-selector">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
                <a href="https://google.com"  target="_blank">Go to Google</a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempus leo id nunc elementum, ut rutrum neque ornare. Pellentesque eu ligula lectus. Duis ac tristique est. Fusce finibus convallis sapien, eu faucibus dui elementum eu. Nunc ultrices magna eros, et lobortis tortor egestas vel. Cras finibus quam auctor fermentum facilisis. Nulla facilisi. In pulvinar purus laoreet, imperdiet quam et, laoreet lectus. Donec in consectetur lorem.
                    Vestibulum accumsan, velit et bibendum varius, orci est tempor lacus, ut vehicula metus sem a libero. Suspendisse elementum turpis sed lacinia blandit. Phasellus sit amet metus metus. Ut vitae molestie orci. Mauris eu nibh in sapien imperdiet tempor. Etiam rhoncus sapien eget diam vulputate volutpat sit amet vel tortor. Phasellus eget sodales nisl.</p>
            </section>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/full stack course/drop-down-proyect/mainn.js"></script>
            <script src="/full stack course/drop-down-proyect/gquery.js"></script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El error está en que el elemento que estas queriendo leer la propiedad, no existe o no fue creado todavía.

Comment: pero sí existe, no hay ningún error de sintaxis? @Vencho

Comment: Lo que sucede es que también para darte una respuesta concreta necesitamos que pongas tu código HTML, quizás el #main no está bien definido o algo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de **@Firefly** es correcta. Lo único que le hizo falta fue explicar el porqué una funciona y la otra no. Cosa que haré en esta respuesta.

Los elementos del DOM **solo pueden tener UN ID**. Y considerando que lo recomendable siempre será que tus elementos tengan **IDs únicos** (de hecho puedes tener 2 o más elementos con el mismo ID, sin embargo **NO es recomendable hacerlo**).

Precisamente por lo que te acabo de explicar `document.getElementById()` siempre regresará **un elemento**, en caso de que encuentre en tu documento el ID especificado como parámetro del método, o **NULL** si no lo encuentra. Mayor información **[aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**.

Sin embargo, no ocurre lo mismo con las **Clases**, pues cada elemento del DOM **puede tener de una a N** clases, y a diferencia del ID con las clases no hay problema alguno que se repitan.

A diferencia del método **getElementById()**, `document.getElementsByClassName()` lo que en realidad te regresa es un arreglo (array) de todos los elementos (nota la **s** en Element**s**) que contengan la clase(s) especificada(s) como parámetro en el método. Mayor información **[aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**.

En la página que te compartí incluye la siguiente descripción:

> nombres es un string que representa la lista de nombres de clase a buscar; los nombres de clase se separan con un espacio

Esto significa que si, por poner un ejemplo, deseas buscar un/los elemento(s) que contengan 2 o más clases (que especifiques como parámetro del método), deberás separarlas con un **espacio**.

Permíteme mostrártelo con un ejemplo:

```js
function contarElementos() {
   var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('primera');
   console.log(elementos);
   alert('Hay ' + elementos.length + ' elementos con la clase «Primera»');
}

function agregarSaludo() {
   
   //Se buscan todos los elementos que contengan las clases (ambas) primera y segunda. NO importa que estén en orden invertido (segundo DIV), o que contengan una tercer clase (tercer DIV).
   var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('primera segunda');
   console.log(elementos);
   alert('Hay ' + elementos.length + ' elementos que contienen las clases «Primera» y «Segunda»');
   
   for(var elemento of elementos) {
      //console.log(elemento);
      elemento.innerHTML += "<label>Saludos Colegas!</label>";
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="primera"></div>
<div class="segunda"></div>
<div class="tercera"></div>

<div class="primera segunda"></div>
<div class="segunda primera"></div>
<div class="primera segunda tercera"></div>

<button onclick="contarElementos()">Contar Elementos</button>&nbsp;
<button onclick="agregarSaludo()">Agregar Saludo</button>
```

Espero haber aclarado tu duda.

Answer (score 2):

Es un pequeño detallito, dejaste un espacio demás, por eso no reconoce ningún elemento con ese id. Sólo tienes que quitar ese espacio y ponerlo:

```
el = el.replace('#', '' );
```

Comment: pero, ¿por qué si puedo dejar ese espacio a la hora de añadirlo a una clase y no con un id?